# Trying make a macro to delete last number of rows and columns in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i am using this script to delete last rows and columns in the current google sheet tab, and it gives me "Those rows are out of bounds." error.
i dont know why , and it works fine when i use integers instead of the 2nd parameter .

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

//Delete rows 201+
sheet.deleteRows(201, sheet.getLastRow() - 200 );

//Delete Columns 10+
sheet.deleteColumns(10, sheet.getLastColumn() - 9 );
```

Comment: getLastRow() gives the last row containing any value.  If the last row used is less than 200 then the second parameter is negative.  Place Logger.log(sheet.getLastRow()) before  the deleteRows command and view the log file to see its value.  The same can be said about getLastColumn().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the answer guys, i should use getMaxRows() to get total number of rows in the sheet and here is the function i used.

```
function delRows51() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.deleteRows(51, ss.getMaxRows() - 50);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

An out of bounds error relates to the methods .deleteRows and .deleteColumns.
The error arises from trying to call a range that doesn't exist. Whether it's because it is trying to call over the maximum number of cells in your sheet, or under it by trying to call a 0th range or even a negative range. You can't call .getRange(0,0) because it doesn't exist and will return your out of range error. 
The problem here is I am.unable to give you the solution since I don't have the context of how you are getting some of your variables. 
What I can do is suggest using a different method. Judging by your code you only want to delete ONE row and ONE column. This is much easier done with .deleteRow(Row) @nd .deleteColumn(Column)
Here is the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteColumn(Integer)
And
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRow(Integer)
If this doesn't help you create a copy of your sheet, remove any sensitive information and share the link with edit permissions so I may look over your code and spreadsheet myself for better context on your problem.

Comment: no i am not trying to delete one row and one column , i`m trying to delete all rows below row number 200 , and all columns after row 9.

Comment: I see, in that case your out of bounds errors are probably being caused by some sort of logical math issue. Can you update your original post using variables instead of set integers like you want? Chances are you're simply over or under counting by one cell causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of simple scripts that might help you.

```
function delLastNRows(n){
  var n=n || 3;//allows you to delete last three rows without passing function a parameter.
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lr=sh.getLastRow();
  if(lr>=n){
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
      sh.deleteRow(sh.getLastRow());
    }
  }
}

function delLastNCols(n){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lc=sh.getLastColumn();
  if(lc>=n){
    for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
      sh.deleteColumn(sh.getLastColumn())
    }
  }
}
```