# How to remove last N rows in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I remove the last N rows of the data range using Google Apps Script?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by last N rows. Are these the last rows of the sheet or the last rows of the data range?

Comment: The data range @Rubén

Comment: Here is a similar question but the OP was looking to remove the last rows of the sheet -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/52679694/1595451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace N with the number of rows you want to delete:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
sheet.deleteRows(lastRow-N-1, N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way if you just have data and no formulas

```
function removeLastN(n=5) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs = vs.filter((r,i) =>i < (vs.length - n));
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
}
```